# i get "internal server error' when i add 'django_social_share' to my installed app

Tags: python, django, apache, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have a web app running on AWS LIGHTSAIL, everything works fine, but on installation of

```
    'django_social_share',
```

and addition to my installed app, I get **internal server error** when the page is refreshed.

Removing **django_social_share** from installed app takes everything back to normal. Please I need help plus if there is any other library I can use to share post.

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you install it via pip? please share your error traceback

Comment: Yes i did, `pip install -r requirements.txt` every other package i installed e.g `widget_tweaks` and `django_filters` is working fine.